# is there a cytoscape.js property change listener?

Tags: cytoscape.js

For Cytoscape Java version there is an official [PropertyUpdatedListener](https://cytoscape.org/javadoc/current_release/org/cytoscape/property/PropertyUpdatedListener.html)

For cytoscape.js I'm not able to find that in the docs, neither an official plugin.
Am I wrong?

Is there a plugin out there, or has anyone done some implementation to enable this functionality?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the document [cytoscaoe.js#events](https://js.cytoscape.org/#events), in the topic `Collection events`:

```
 
You can listen to these events for collections
* position : when an element changes position
* data : when an element’s data is changed
* style : when an element’s style is changed
```

A collection contains a set of nodes and edges. Calling a function applies the function to all elements in the collection. When a collection is bound to an event, all elements in the collection are set to listen to that event.

Comment: precisely what I've been looking for. Remark: 'data' only triggers when the change happens via the ele*.data(key, value) function - the actual data isn't observed